# How to write a sed function that finds a character not between quotes on OS X

Tags: regex, macos

I'm trying to write a sed command that replaces all commas that are not between quotes with the word 'linux'. Unfortunately, it's not working and I would like to know why.

**My command:**

`sed -i '.bak' -e 's;,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$);linux;g' file.txt`

I tested the regex (`/,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g`) between the semicolons on regexr.com and it's working as expected. When running my command the file does not change. I'm running this command from macOS that's why I specify the backup extension.

file.txt contains the following text and the first comma should be replaced with 'linux':
`a matching comma, "a non-matching comma,"`

Using `sed -i '.bak' -e 's;comma;linux;g' file.txt` works fine and replaces both words with 'linux'.

Let me know how I could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post samples of input and expected output too in your question, that will make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OS X doesn't use GNU sed.

Comment: sed uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions, which do not support advanced features like lookahead.

Comment: But GNU sed can be compiled from its source code on MacOSX

Comment: @Frogical: Use `perl` instead of `sed` to use a lookahead regex

Comment: As written, you are looking for literal parentheses and question marks which don't exist in your text.  Your regex looks like PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression).  Although GNU Grep can be compiled with support for PCRE, I am not aware of that being possible with GNU Sed (though it won't surprise me to find I'm out of touch).  But even with extended regular expressions enabled (`-E` option for macOS `sed`), what you've written won't work with `sed`.  You'll probably do best using Perl.  Avoid using `-i .bak` until you know you `sed` script works.

Comment: Also, it has not been OS X for a while now; it is macOS.  The current version is Big Sur, 11.3.1 or thereabouts (and the change from 10.x to 11.x is one reason why Apple dropped the X from the moniker).

Answer (score 0):

As usual, when it comes to matching some pattern in specific contexts, it makes sense to use `perl` instead of `sed`:

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|,/linux/g' file
```

The regex matches

- `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - omit the found match and force the regex engine to start searching for another match at the location where the index was located
- `|` - or
- `,` - a comma.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/0azO1g):

```sh
s='one , two , "three , four" , five'
perl -pe 's/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|,/linux/g' <<< "$s"
# => one linux two linux "three , four" linux five
```